# Using PHP PCRE to fetch div content

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to fetch data from a div (based on his id), using PHP's PCRE. The goal is to fetch div's contents based on his id, and using recursivity / depth to get everything inside it. The main problem here is to get other divs inside the "main div", because regex would stop once it gets the next **`</div>`** it finds after the initial **`<div id="test">`**.


I've tryed so many different approaches to the subject, and none of it worked. The best solution, in my oppinion, is to use the **R** parameter (Recursion), but never got it to work properly.
Any Ideais?
Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be much better off using some form of DOM parser - regex really isn't suited to this problem. If all you want is basic HTML dom parsing, something like [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) would be right up your alley. It's trivial to install (just include a single PHP file) and trivial to use (2-3 lines will do what you need).

```
include('simple-html-dom.php');

$dom = str_get_html($bunchofhtmlcode);
$testdiv = $dom->find('div#test',0); // 0 for the first occurrence
$testdiv_contents = $testdiv->innertext;
```